# Exciting examples showcasing how Dart can play nicely with others?

Tags: mongodb, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, flot, dart

I am havin a look at Dart and I am wondering if there are examples showcasing how to create a nice looking webapp (think Bootstrap, Foundation etc) that relies on thirdparty libraries like (e.g jquery-ui, bootstrap addons, flot etc) with some dynamic sample data (mongodb, ...)?

I did browse around a little but I was looking for something a bit more convincing than http://dart-lang.github.com/js-interop/example or the ToDo apps.

Answer (score 0):

The most important URLs for this are http://www.dartlang.org/samples/ and https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/samples/. Our hope is to have more full-stack demos in the coming months such as the book store example in "Agile Web Development with Rails". However, right now, we're really focused on rich client-side web application development (such as our Web UI framework and its version of the TodoMVC sample).

Comment: I had already looked at most of those samples and even though the ToDoMVC doesn't look too bad it was a bit of a "meh" I am afraid.  The various web frameworks we have now with stuff like grid systems, responsive designs, reusable components and js plugins weren't as prominent when Rails came on the scene, so I am looking forward to seeing some modern looking full-stack demos and not just a Dart version of the Rails "book store" example in the coming months then.  I will be watching this space :)

Comment: I hear you :) We'll get there. When you create a new language, a new set of libraries, a new editor, a new framework, etc. there's an awful lot of work that needs to be done. Hence, it takes a while to catch up with the guys who only had to create a framework. However, solving all the problems that make rich, client-side, web application development hard is a difficult problem. Dart is a pretty ambitious project, and it tries to tackle a lot of problems at the same time, in a fairly holistic manner.